# Javascript code issues with flask development

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am new to Flask development. I have two buttons on my HTML form. One of button executes a python script when clicked on and hence is integrated in flask script. While, the other button just clears up the form using javascript code.
Unfortunately, the javascript button is also navigating to flask code in the debug mode.

The code works fine without flask environment. However, somehow flask is preceeding javascript. Other functions of javascript are working as usual.

```
<script  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}" ></script>

<div class="form-submit">
<input type="submit" value="Reset All" class="submit" name="reset" id="reset" class ="resetClass"/>
<a href=”/submit_form_main”><input type="submit" value="Save and Generate" class="submitClass" name="submit" id="submit" /></a>                        </div>
```

```
      $('#reset').on('click', function(){
          $('#register-form').reset();
      });
```

```py
@app.route('/main', methods=['POST'])
def submit_form():
    try:
        submit_form_main()
    except:
        submit_form_main2()
```

jQuery code is not working anymore. It gives an error 'reset is not a function'
Then, it goes to flask side of the code and breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this doesn't actually point to a Flask route:

```html
<a href=”/submit_form_main”>
```

Try changing it to

```html
<a href="{{url_for('submit_form')}}">
```

or

```html
<a href="/main">
```

The first example uses Jinja to template the route/URL associated with your `def submit_form():` method, and the second example just uses the URL directly.

As you currently have it, you're trying to call a backend function directly through `<a href>`, but that is supposed to specify the URL/route to visit, which *then* invokes a method based on whatever back-end logic you have written for that route.

Also: it wasn't in the snippet/example you posted, so make sure you are loading jQuery.

Comment: Hello, 
I am using jquery correctly and it is being loaded like   
````html   <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}" ></script> ````
I changed the submit_form according to the first method, but I think it is working on the basis of my route function. I have 3 functions that operate differently on same route.

Answer (score 0):

If he gives you that message, it may be because the jquery library is not loading properly. Make sure that there is no js code that is giving any error which can block the load of the jquery. Most often it is that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried loading them. The same code works when run without flask integration. 
````html      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}" ></script> ````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jQuery is the one causing issues with flask. So as a workaround, the clearing of variables one by one with javascript works fine.
Somehow, the reset of form with document.getElementById('register-form').reset() also does not work.
Both jQuery and Javascript give error "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function".

As for the issue with flask, it goes to the server code for every POST request if input type is "submit". I changed the input type to "button" and it does not go to flask code anymore.